# Are the terms 'service endpoint' and 'service access point' synonymous?

Tags: service-provider

Both terms are used quite a bit in technical documents here and there. Do they mean exactly the same thing? Or are there nuances if one is to be pedantic? I suspect a service access point (where a service provider connects to a wider network) is physical and a service endpoint is logical, but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Service Access Point (SAP)

A SAP is a logical entity that serves as the customer's point of access into a service. Each subscriber service is configured with at least one SAP. A SAP can only be configured on a port that has been configured specifically as an 'access' port. A SAP is the subscriber-side entry and exit point for a service.

Service Endpoint

In IP/MPLS network there are different types of services such as L2VPN, L3VPN (VPLS, VPRN). These services have endpoints in different PE routers. Service Endpoint term is used to identify the PE router which is the endpoint of that specific service. Basically, service tunnel represented by the service labels signaled end-to-end by the two PEs that are the service endpoints.